# Create a Crystal Report using SQL Query

Tags: crystal-reports, hana, sapb1

I am trying to create a Crystal Report using the following Tables from SAP Business One: `OINV`, `INV1`, `OITM` and a table from an add-on "@argns_color"

I have been using the following query:

```
select t0."DocDate",t0."DocNum",t0."CardCode",t0."CardName",t1."ItemCode",T1."Dscription",t1."Quantity",t2."U_ARGNS_COL"  "Codigo Color",t3."U_ColDesc"  "nombre color",t3."U_NRFCode"  "pantone",t2."U_ARGNS_MOD" "estilo",t2."U_ARGNS_SIZE" "talla"from "OINV" t0inner join "INV1" t1 on t0."DocEntry" = t1."DocEntry"inner join "OITM" t2 on t1."ItemCode"=t2."ItemCode"inner join "@ARGNS_COLOR" t3 on t2."U_ARGNS_COL"=t3."U_ColCode"
```

The only fields I need for my report are the following:

`DocNum`, `ItemCode`, `Dscription`, `Quantity`, `U_ARGNS_COL`, `"U_ColDesc"`, `"U_ARGNS_SIZE"`.

Is there a way in crystal reports where I can Execute the query or do I have to use the old drag and drop way from Field Explorer?

Thank You

Jose

Comment: Probably a Cross Tab Report might be the solution for this problem. I want to create a small report that has one row for a particular SKU item, then in a matrix it will show me Size and Quantity Relationship. Right now when I execute the report it gives me the results in rows Say if there are 5 Small and 4 medium of item X it will write down 5 rows to represent those 5 items and other 4 rows representing the other 4 items making a total of 9 rows.  , but I want them to appear only in one Row with a small matrix showing 5 of Size Small and 4 of size Medium. Hope this clarifies the question.